# Disable annoying comment highlighting in emacs

Tags: emacs, colors, elisp

I have started programming scheme, and I noticed the scheme minor mode highlights comments in the most obnoxious way possible when using solarized dark (color-theme-solarized). This also occurs on elisp files.

Is there a way I can disable highlighting? It's making the code unreadable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on http://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just run:

```
(font-lock-mode 0)
```

Or interactively, you can toggle this behavior with M-`x` `font-lock-mode`.

More information is here:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Font-Lock.html#Font-Lock

If you want to customize just the comment face, then you can do this with M-`x customize`.  Click on `Faces`, then `Font lock`, then `Font lock faces`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is almost perfect. font-lock-mode turns off syntax highlighting entirely it appears - I just want the comments to not be backed by a super bright grey background.

Comment: @Steve: Then the easiest thing to do is M-`x customize` and click on `Faces`, then `Font Lock` then `Font Lock Faces`.  Whatever weird face you don't like you can probably change there.